# Basic hangman program in Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, netbeans, conditional-statements

I need to get the condition to follow whether the alphabet is  x y z and I can't get the logic of it.

```
package guessword;

import java.util.*;

public class Guessword {       
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        System.out.println("Guess The seven letter word\nPress Enter");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("");
        for(int a=1;a<=7;a++){
            System.out.println("Attempt "+a);
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));       
            if(a=='a') {
                System.out.println("- - - - - a -"); 
            }
            else if(a=='g'){
                System.out.println("- - - g - - -");
            }
            else if(a=='m') {
                System.out.println("- - -  - - m");
            }
            else if(a=='o') {
                System.out.println("- - o  - - -");
            }
            else if(a=='p'){
                System.out.println("p - -  - - -");
            }
            else if(a=='r'){
                System.out.println("- r -  - - -");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Give it another go!");
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This is how it is giving output:

```
Guess The seven letter word
Press Enter

Attempt 1
a
[a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]
Give it another go!
Attempt 2
```

and on this `[a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]` line I wish it did not print this. but the condition.

Comment: Let's back up a bit. Think about how you're printing out the hints, like `"- r -  - - -"`.  Now on round two you need to make 6 more strings to get the 2 letter guess. If you do this for every possibility, for an `n` lettered word, you'd need to define `O(2^n)` number of strings. This clearly cant be the best solution. Imagine if the secret word was supplied by the user (ie, you didn't know what the word was going to be before you started the game). How do you think you can handle that in code?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking the wrong input, because `a` is a number and the user input is `input`. Also you are comparing `String` so you have to use `equals` like this:

```
if(input.equals("a")) {
    System.out.println("- - - - - a -"); 
} else if(input.equals("g")) {
    System.out.println("- - - g - - -");
} else if(input.equals("m")) {
    System.out.println("- - -  - - m");
} // and so on...
```

And you might want to initialize `Scanner` before the main loop and close it after it, like this:

```
scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int a=1;a<=7;a++){
    System.out.println("Attempt "+a);
    // some code ...
}
scanner.close();
```

last but not least, you are printing the array every time when you call this `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));`, so you have to remove it if you do not want it to appear on console.